# To solve for $x,y,n$ in non-negative integers , $\dfrac{x!+y!}{n!}=p^n$ , $p$ a given prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

Let $p$ be a given prime , then how do we find non-negative integers $(x,y,n)$ $\space$ , such that

$\dfrac{x!+y!}{n!}=p^n$ ?

Comment: Did you check what conditions you need for $\frac{x!+y!}{n!}$ to be an integer?

Comment: For $p=2,3$, the solutions are trivial as $n=1$ can be chosen & $p$ would be a sum of $2$ factorials. However, for $p=5$, by showing that $n!\,p^n$ can't be written as a sum of $2$ factorials, there is *no* solution with $n\leq7$ (unless I've made a mistake). This gives $x!+y!$ as *at least* $1.5\times10^{10}$ (if a solution exists) which is rather large so I think this might be quite difficult.